# Achieving a light refraction/dispersion effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blender

I've been intrigued by the "hello" backgrounds for macOS (which rolled out with the new iMac)— particularly, the subtle light refraction/dispersion effect: [image: Screenshot of one of apple's new backgrounds]

Does anyone know how I could possibly replicate this? Would something like this be possible in Photoshop, or would this require the use of Blender to imitate light.

Comment: It would be possible to recreate this exact image in Photoshop more or less, but a dynamic solution which works with any arbitrary layers would be tricky. Do you have a particular design where you want to apply this effect?

Comment: Not a particular design yet, but would love to make use of the effect— something similar to the way a magnifying glass refracts light

Comment: This is not like refraction in a lens, it's like two tubes made of thin partially transparent colored plastic lean against each other. The color variations resemble what's got by using polarization filter in the camera and to some degree linearly polarized light. Internal stress variations in the material causes color variations. Magnifying glass causes distortion and chromatic aberration. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration

Comment: (continued) Low quality lens simulations are commonly available; also for free. In GDSE you'll find several cases of it.